# Android: Can't identify the correct answer in a quiz game

Tags: android, multiple-choice

Well, I'm with this problem about 3 days. I'm making a quiz game, but I can't identify if the clicked button contains the correct answer or not. Following some tips that I saw around here, I did some alterations in my code. See the new code:

```
package com.app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    TextView textView1, textView2;
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

    ArrayList<Question> qsts = new ArrayList<Question>();
    List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    ArrayList<String> allAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

    Random rng = new Random();
    Question nextQuestion;


// Creating the objects Question that recieves the values "questionText", "correctAnswerText", and the other 3 wrong answers "wrongAnswer1" 2 and 3...

    Question q1 = new Question(
            "Question 1",

            "Correct Answer - Question 1",
            "Wrong 1 - Question 1",
            "Wrong 2 - Question 1",
            "Wrong 3 - Question 1"
            );
    Question q2 = new Question(
            "Question 2",

            "Correct Answer - Question 2",
            "Wrong 1 - Question 2",
            "Wrong 2 - Question 2",
            "Wrong 3 - Question 2"
            );
    Question q3 = new Question(
            "Question 3",

            "Correct Answer - Question 3",
            "Wrong 1 - Question 3",
            "Wrong 2 - Question 3",
            "Wrong 3 - Question 3"
            );

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_other);


    // ADD THE QUESTIONS IN THE ArrayList qsts

    qsts.add(q1);           
        qsts.add(q2);
        qsts.add(q3);

        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
            btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);

            btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn4.setOnClickListener(this);

        generateQuestion();

    }

        public void generateQuestion(){




            while(true){

                int nxt = rng.nextInt(3);

                if (!generated.contains(nxt)){

                    generated.add(nxt);

                    Question nextQuestion = qsts.get(nxt);

                    textView1.setText(nextQuestion.questionText);

                    allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText);
                    allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer1);
                    allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer2);
                    allAnswers.add(nextQuestion.wrongAnswer3);

                    Collections.shuffle(allAnswers);

                    btn1.setText(allAnswers.get(0));
                    btn2.setText(allAnswers.get(1));
                    btn3.setText(allAnswers.get(2));
                    btn4.setText(allAnswers.get(3));

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button)v;
            String buttonText = b.getText().toString();

            if(buttonText.equals(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText))
            { 

                textView2.setText("CORRECT!");
                generateQuestion();
                return;

            }else{
                textView2.setText("WRONG!");
                generateQuestion();
                return;
            }

        }
}
```

I was creating the objects in the Question class code and was working with `static` objects, but following the tips, I made that way.

Here is the class code:

```
package com.app;

public class Question {

    String questionText;
    String correctAnswerText;       
    String wrongAnswer1;
    String wrongAnswer2;
    String wrongAnswer3;


    Question (String qst, String cAns, String wAns1, String wAns2, String wAns3){

        questionText = qst;
        correctAnswerText = cAns;
        wrongAnswer1 = wAns1;
        wrongAnswer2 = wAns2;
        wrongAnswer3 = wAns3;

    }
```

I know the problem is in the comparation of the `if` in the onClick method, 'cause when I compare the String buttonText with something else, it works. Please, someone tell me why I can't compare with the `nextQuestion.correctAnswerText`. Am I declaring something in the wrong place?

Observation: the app stops when I click one of the 4 buttons that contains the answer (correct or wrong)

Comment: `Observation: the app stops`  What do you mean, the app stops?  It crashes?

Comment: Is it your exact code.

Comment: Yeah, @Simon. It crashes. Sorry, it's not my first language

Comment: Yes, @Vishal. The code is the same

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.  If you don't know how to, please ask.

Comment: @Simon, I uploaded the log.txt (with just the error part) file here: [link](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=WbwoN)

Comment: Vijal answer is right. just remove the Question in Question nextQuestion = qsts.get(nxt);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your are declaring `Question nextQuestion` twice.
One Globally and another one in function `generateQuestion()`

And the global `nextQuestion` is null and that is your error.

Replace this(`Question nextQuestion = qsts.get(nxt);`)  line in function  `generateQuestion()` with `nextQuestion = qsts.get(nxt);`

**Solution for your comment.**
`allAnswers.clear()` do this before generating new question.

```
     if(buttonText.equals(nextQuestion.correctAnswerText))
        { 

            textView2.setText("CORRECT!");
            allAnswers.clear();
            generateQuestion();
            return;

        }else{
            textView2.setText("WRONG!");
            allAnswers.clear();
            generateQuestion();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad.  The overriding design principle is that all variables should have the shortest possible life span.  A class field is probably appropriate in this case but definitely not a global.

Comment: @Simon I know global variable are bad habit

Comment: So if you know, why are you proposing it as an answer?

Comment: @Simon Vishal Vijay is right. Unfortunately, he uses the word Globally for class member. The class member nextQuestion is null because he declares a local nextQuestion in generateQuestion. Thus the class member nextQuestion is not assigned there.

Comment: @VishalVijay, it helped me, man. But the problem now is that all the answers get mixed. The answers of the 1st question get mixed with the answers of the 2nd and respectively.

Comment: Without the `while(true)` I can't generate a new random number that picks up the **different** question. I tried here, but the answers still getting mixed

Comment: I understood .Thats why I removed that comment

Comment: See the solution in answer

Comment: Ya it is the problem of allAnswers. You are not clearing it before generating new qustn

Comment: Man, I believe you made my day. Let me just make some tests and I will make your answer my accepted answer, ok?